# Google Maps SDK iOS Getting co-ordinates from a user input

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, location, latitude-longitude

I am looking to add functionality to my app where the user can input a location name like 'London' or 'New York' and I would like it to search google maps for co-ordinates. Similar to the approach used in the google maps app.

After I have the co-ordinate I can add the marker Im just unsure how to search a user input to find a place latitude and longitude.

Any help appriciated,

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for that you need to use Google Geocoding . It is as simple as getting data through HTTP and parsing it (it can return JSON )
check this api https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/?csw=1#GeocodingRequests

try like this

```
- (CLLocationCoordinate2D) geoCodeUsingAddress:(NSString *)address
{
    double latitude = 0, longitude = 0;
    NSString *youraddr =  [address stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSString *req = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&address=%@", youraddr];
    NSString *result = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:req] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
    if (result) {
        NSScanner *scanneCoordinate = [NSScanner scannerWithString:result];
        if ([scanneCoordinate scanUpToString:@"\"lat\" :" intoString:nil] && [scanneCoordinate scanString:@"\"lat\" :" intoString:nil]) {
            [scanneCoordinate scanDouble:&latitude];
            if ([scanneCoordinate scanUpToString:@"\"lng\" :" intoString:nil] && [scanneCoordinate scanString:@"\"lng\" :" intoString:nil]) {
                [scanneCoordinate scanDouble:&longitude];
            }
        }
    }
    CLLocationCoordinate2D latitudelongitudeCoordinate;
    NSLog(" longitude==%ul", center. latitude);
 NSLog(" longitude==%ul", center.longitude);
    return latitudelongitudeCoordinate;
}
```

Comment: This has got me close! Im getting some weird outputs so i'll need to debug it, but I feel its close. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks, i've found the problem. It gets the Latitude and Longitude well. and stores them in the double values fine. But when I call newLocation.latitude or newLocation.longitude (Newly created from this method) it comes out as inf or something strange. Any ideas?

Comment: Fine to test it this way, but I would caution you not to do this synchronously as shown above. It will block the main thread until it returns.

Comment: And since the service is returning JSON, you should use NSJSONSerialization to get the data rather than scanning the string.

Comment: I see. I saw it on googles documentation. It just seemed a little difficult to follow. Probably doesn't help that I have no knowlege of JSON

Answer (score 1):

You are using GoogleMaps, So I would suggest you to use googleAPI for geocoding.

Example

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=London&key=API_KEY

Documentation :

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#GeocodingRequests

Hope this will help you......

Answer (score 0):

The process of converting locations into latitude/longitude coordinates is called geocoding. There are literally dozens of providers for this information, some free other paid. Just search for "geocoding API".

One of my favorites is [ArcGIS](https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/geocode/api-reference/overview-world-geocoding-service.htm). It offers free geocoding services so long as you do not store the results in a database.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not tied to using Google, you can use `CLGeocoder` directly from MapKit.
Its method `geocodeAddressString:completionHandler:` does exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: This method is built-in into MapKit. It uses Apple's servers to determine the coordinates, not Google's.

Comment: You can use CLGeocoder even when using Google's map. According to Apple: "You can use geocoder objects either in conjunction with, or independent of, the classes of the Map Kit framework."

Comment: @picciano Yes that's correct. However, `CLGeocoder` uses Apple's map service to determine the locations, and they might be different from the ones that Google finds.